# How can I update access token automatically and use it on socket connection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, local-storage

I have a access token and socket connection. But there is a problem, when I logout and login user again access token don't update itself automatically. That's why my socket connection keep works on before access token.

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

const socket = io("https://localhost:3000", {
  extraHeaders: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  },
});

socket.on("connect", () => {
  // Socket connection is established
  console.log(socket);
  console.log("Socket connected");
});

socket.on("connect_error", (error) => {
  // Connection error occurred
  console.error("Socket connection error:", error);
});

socket.on("connect_timeout", (timeout) => {
  // Connection timeout occurred
  console.error("Socket connection timeout:", timeout);
});

socket.on("error", (error) => {
  // Generic error event
  console.error("Socket error:", error);
});

export default socket;
```

That's my socketUtils. How can I automatically update my accessToken and create new socket connection when accesstoken changes on my local storage ? I have tried windows.addEventListener("storage") but it needs refresh to get accessToken, and I have tried to use this socketUtils in react component but it gives me can not listen (on) something like that. How can I handle with this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a separate function that'll do that for you, check this :

```
import initializeSocket from "./socketUtils";

let socket = null;

const listenForTokenChanges = () => {
  window.addEventListener("storage", (event) => {
    if (event.key === "accessToken") {
      const newAccessToken = event.newValue;
      if (newAccessToken) {
        if (socket) {
          socket.disconnect();
        }
        socket = initializeSocket(newAccessToken);
      }
    }
  });
};

export { listenForTokenChanges };
```

and then import it in the component that you're working on and use it with UseEffect(callback, []).

Something like this:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { listenForTokenChanges } from "./tokenUtils";

const YourComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    listenForTokenChanges();
  }, []);

  // Component rendering
};

export default YourComponent;
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, window.addEventListener just works when I refresh or open new tab. It doesn't work with routes. I have tried this solution :(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).